# How to save a disabled Game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, disable

So I have a button in my game and when I click it, it disables from script

```
MyGameobject.SetActive(false)
```

But the problem is that when I restart the game the disabled gameobject is enabled again. So my question is how do I save the disabled gameobject ?

I tried using PlayerPrefs, but I realised that it makes no sense. Or does it?

Comment: Do you have a class that saves the state for your entire game? If so, you can save the state of the button there.

Comment: `but I realised that it makes no sense.` ... why not? You just need some unique identifier ..

Comment: Why does it not make sense to use PlayerPrefs?:) If it really is just one object, create an entry for example like this: ```PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ObjectActiveState", 0)``` (0 for disabled, anything else for enabled). On restart of the game, check this entry: ```PlayerPrefs.GetInt(ObjectActiveState)``` and enable/disable your gameobject accordingly. You could even use the Integer directly to set the active state.

Comment: The playerprefs won't get you a gameobject. Just an integer which you have to convert to boolean, and then use to set the object active or not. You'd want something like `Mygameobject.SetActive(Convert.ToBoolean(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("GameobjectActiveState",1)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PlayerPrefs`:

```
public GameObject MyGameObject;

void Start()
{
    // Check on start if gameobject should be enabled or disabled
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyGoActiveState") == 0)
    {
        // Should be disabled
        MyGameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        // Should be enabled
        MyGameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

// Assuming this is your callback for disabling the object
public void DisableGameObject()
{
    // Disable gameobject
    MyGameObject.SetActive(false);

    // Store in PlayerPrefs that gameobject is disabled
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyGoActiveState", 0);
}

// Assuming this is your callback for enabling the object
public void EnableGameObject()
{
    // Enable gameobject
    MyGameObject.SetActive(true);

    // Store in PlayerPrefs that gameobject is enabled
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyGoActiveState", 1);
}
```

For one-line fans one could also set the active state like this, assuming 0 is used to indicate disabled and anything else means enabled:

```
MyGameObject.SetActive(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyGoActiveState") == 0);
```

Comment: Wow thank you, yor really helped me out!